# kotlin android dialogfragment called from fragment not connecting with caller

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, modal-dialog, asynccallback

BottomSheetDialogFragment

my stack at this point is this :
mainactivity
List1(a selector fragment , navigation start)
card (a detail fragment, navigation destination)
list2 (a selector fragment, navigation destination)
YesNoDialog (a BottomSheetDialogFragment fragment)

list1, card and list2 are in a navigation graph

i implemented the interface in the list2 fragment and am trying to callback to the list2 to the YesNoDialog.
 no matter which technique is used (onAttach onViewCreated onClick in dialog, there is not yesNoListener instantiated

```
try{
        Log.d(QuestionGroupList.TAG, parentFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(QuestionGroupList.TAG)?.tag + "tag")
        yesNoListener = (parentFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(QuestionGroupList.TAG) as iYesNoDialogListener)
    }
    catch(e: ClassCastException){}
    try{
        Log.d(QuestionGroupList.TAG, (parentFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(parentFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount-1).id.toString()))
        yesNoListener = (parentFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(parentFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount-1) as iYesNoDialogListener)
    }
catch(e: ClassCastException){}
    try{
        Log.d(QuestionGroupList.TAG, targetFragment?.tag +"tag")
        yesNoListener = targetFragment as iYesNoDialogListener
    }
    catch(e: ClassCastException){}
    try{
        Log.d(QuestionGroupList.TAG, context?.toString() +"tag")
        yesNoListener  = context as iYesNoDialogListener
    }
    catch(e: ClassCastException){}
}
yesNoListener.onFinishYesNoDialog(true)
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly your problem ?

Comment: I have a three level navigation graph where the last fragment needs to display a dialog to prompt the user for a decision. Getting the the bottomsheetdialogfragment works well and the button methods call sends the decision to the top level activity. THe top level activity implements the interface for the method from the button. I could not get the third fragment to acknowledge the method execution using the 6 or 7 techniques found on the internet. I need the calling fragment to be responding to the method execution.